# Handling HEIC/HEIF photos

Tags: images, contact-image

If we try to upload an .heic file for a contact image, we get this error: "Image could not be uploaded due to invalid type extension."

Is there a way to enable Civi to accept and display heic/heif images?

Answer (score 1):

This is hard-coded at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/c8a7531ec9785161f4cdc6b1d51e9ff01989db47/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php#L1180

But I'm sure core would be open to updating that list. You could make either a github PR or lab ticket at https://lab.civicrm.org.

Comment: I added it there. Unfortunately, same error.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood where you were uploading it. Will update answer.